# JSON not parsing to Model in Controller Action in Jquery Post

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to call an action in a controller with the data I get from my Javascript. The Action gets called but all the variables in the Model parameter stay 'null'.

In the javascript I call the controller action and I put in the data object as a json object with the same variables as the Model.

Javascript:

```
            ...........
            attachments.push(
                        {
                            "Name": a.name,
                            "MimeType": a.type,
                            "File": a.data,
                            "Size": a.size
                        });

            var new_message = {
                Title: $('#sendSubject').val(),
                Body: $('#sendContent').val(),
                Receiver: $("#topicTo").val(),
                Attachments: attachments
            }

            $.ajax({
                url: 'MAjax/AddMessage',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(new_message)
            })
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult AddMessage(MessageModel message)  <--- message's variables are null
        {
          ....
        }
```

Model:

```
public class MessageModel
    {
        public string ConversationId;

        public string Title;

        public string Body;

        public string Receiver;

        public List<AttachmentModel> Attachments;
}
```

All the variables seem to match but how could it be that when the code reaches the controller action, all the variables on the MessageModel are null?

Can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong